# GIDSignInButton requires two finger tap to launch Google sign in flow

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, gidsignin

I'm implementing Google's SignIn SDK in my app, and while everything works, the GIDSignButton requires a two finger tap in order to launch the OAuth flow.

Here's all the relevant code:

In `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

In `LoginViewController.swift`

```
let googleLoginButton: GIDSignInButton = {
    let button = GIDSignInButton()
    button.colorScheme = .Light
    button.style = .IconOnly
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring with Google services: \(configureError)")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

    view.addSubview(googleLoginButton)
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // Success
    } else {
       // Failure
    }

}
```

Again, the actual Google sign in works, but the button requires a two finger tap to work. How can I get it to work like a normal button (only one finger required)?

Comment: I had a similar issue, in my case it was a tap gesture recognizer in the main view that was causing the problem, setting false to the recognizer's `cancelsTouchesInView` solved the problem